# How to find length of line intersecting trapezoid?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I want a way to calculate the length of a line that interests a trapezoid and is parallel to the bases. I have seen how to calculate the midsegment and how to use the similar triangles method but the only examples I saw for it involved isosceles trapezoids.
Is there a method that works for all sorts of trapezoids?

Clarification: in my calculus textbook I have questions involving an area shaped like a trapezoid and I want to take integral over that area But to do that I need to be able to find the length of all line segments parallel to base that intersect the trapezoid.
[image]
Here is the question in my textbook example. But here the trapezoid is isosceles. I want to know if this method works for other types of trapezoids.

For example let's consider this trapezoid in this image:[image: non isocelestrapezoid]
I want to calculate the length of the segment tgat is parallel to the bases and intersects the legs, and has hight 1 cm.
Or any arbitrary hight between the two bases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for replying i did clarify how i encountered this question in my edit

Comment: It would help if you give an example of a non-isosceles trapezoid. For example, what information (side lengths, angles) do you know about the trapezoid and the position of the line you want to calculate the length of?

Comment: Tony Mathew i added an example at the end of the question if you could show me how to solve it that would be great.

Comment: This is fairly simple.  Just express the two lateral sides as linear functions of the height.  This simple, it just two lines.  So you for the left side $x_1 = f(y)$ and for the rigth side $x_2 = g(y) $.  The required length is $\ell = x_2 - x_1 = g(y) - f(y) $

Comment: Hosam H are you solving the last problem i shared in the question? If so can you apply this method on the actual numerical values in the pic.